# How to test Third party library functions in angular unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, printf, karma-jasmine

I am testing angular services using angular unit testing with karma and jasmine . 
In my services I have used sprintf() of sprintf-js module to get the generate string . Now when I tried to test service it gives **error sprintf not defined** .

code is something like this :

**myservice.js**

```
abc(a,b){
var url = sprintf(a,b);
ajax.get(url);
}
```

**myservice.spec.js** : I have injected the myservice in this file and used it -

```
myservice.abc(dummya, dummyb);

$rootScope.$appy();

expect(myservice.abc).toHaveBeenCalled();

Any help appreciated .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the third party libraries to function currently in tests, add them as a dependency for the service.

`angular.module('my-defined-module-name').constant('sprintf',window.sprintf)`

```
angular.service('my-service',['sprintf',function(sprintf){

}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there no other way, otherwise I have to make a lot of changes in my code ? As currently I have required the sprintf-js in my app.js and used its functionality globally .

Comment: @SumitChaudhari This is the only way i know, there could be other possibilities.